# Can PyCharm be used with ptvsd?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, pycharm, aws-sam

I would like to debug an application that runs inside a docker container that I don't have SSH access to and therefore can't use the debug server run configuration (because it's AWS SAM but that doesn't really matter).

What I have managed to do is debug the application in vscode by using ptvsd and creating the right `launch.json` in vscode. My question is, can I do the same in pycharm, create a run configuration that attaches to the process and works with ptvsd?